# How to include dynamically generated data in module.exports

Tags: node.js, mongodb, requirejs

Anything written in javascript file gets exported using module.exports. How can I export data if it is fetched from mongodb and not already written in static file.
 I have seen that only static data is exported to other modules and not that is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You could export a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or a function that returns a promise:

```
// dynamicData.js
const dataPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // load some data from mongo
  db.fetchSomeData((error, result) => {
    if(error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(result);
    }
  });
});

function getData() {
  return dataPromise;
}

module.exports = getData;
```

However, you'll have to use the data asynchronously:

```
// someModule.js
const dynamicData = require("./dynamicData");

dynamicData().then((data) => {
  // use your async data
});
```

Alternatively, you could load the data before any other application code is run, cache it, and access the cached value:

```
let data = null;

function load() {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // load some data from mongo
    db.fetchSomeData((error, result) => {
      if(error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        data = result;
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
}

function getData() {
  return data;
}

module.exports = {load, getData};
```

Load at startup:

```
const dynamicData = require("./dynamicData");

dynamicData.load()
  .then(() => {
    // start application
    const data = dynamicData.getData();
  });
```

Another option might be the [mongo-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sync) module for working with mongo databases synchronously.